# htaccess redirect if the url is not included index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is right links:

http://digitalpoint.com.bannedadsense.com

http://businessinsider.com.bannedadsense.com

http://caradvice.com.au.bannedadsense.com

http://bannedadsense.com/index.php

And here is wrong link:

http://bannedadsense.com/

http://bannedadsense.com

This is htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*).html$ index.php?domainname=$1 [L]
```

you can see the title of this post, it is problem. or when you go to [bannedadsense.com](http://bannedadsense.com) you will see it redirect to new bad url, it should be still in homepage, now it wrong. If you go to [bannedadsense.com/index.php](http://bannedadsense.com/index.php) then no problem. I need to fix this problem.

Please help me fix the problem in htaccess.

Comment: If you ask us to fix your problem you should first explain what the problem actually is. You just dumped some lines of code and a list of URLs. That is not an explanation.

Comment: sorry, there are all code of htaccess

Comment: Which is even less an explanation of _the problem_. Voting to close this question.

Comment: you can see the title of this post, it is problem. or when go to here http://bannedadsense.com/ you will see the problem, if you go to http://bannedadsense.com/index.php then no problem.

Comment: what is the problem you don't want to show index.php `bannedadsense.com` to this url?

Comment: Yes, when i go to http://bannedadsense.com, the website broken, i want when go to there i will see home page the same when go to http://bannedadsense.com/index.php

Comment: Try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` at top of your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Add that in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i have tried with this code, but when i go to http://bannedadsense.com/ the problem is the same

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*).html$ index.php?domainname=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [R]
```